# Linking data to road colour scheme

Tags: qgis, color, road

I'm getting started with a QGIS map showing the quality of roads in my town. I have various data which create an index of 1-5.

How do I link this index data to road data in a map, showing the bad roads (5) in red, and good roads (1) in green?

Comment: How is your index data related to the roads?  ie use your common identifier field to execute a join.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to create is either a categorized or graduated symbology.  This website walks you through it: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-styling-vector-data-in-qgis.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your trying to create a spatial matrix on your road layer from other intersecting layers.  To populate the road layer you will need to perform either a combination of Join Attribute by Location, Spatial Query, or Union.

**Spatial Query** - will select one table features based on spatial intersection parameter.  You may find the tool in the *Vector menu>Spatial Query>Spatial Query*.

**Join Attribute by Location** - will join the two tables together based on spatial intersection.  You may find the tool in the *Vector menu>Data Management>Join Attribute by Location*.

**Union** - You should be mindful of that the joining of spatial data between polyline and polygon data is not always a one to one relationship, since sometimes polyline features overlap polygon features.  Union tool is located in the *Vector menu>Geoprocessing Tools>Union*.

With each method you will most likely have to clean up your final database eliminating un-wanted fields and devising a matrix schema for each criteria (or field) that may add up to the total classified field (summation of the other criteria fields).